# Excel formula issue using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a python script to get data from the website and write it to excel. Each time script runs in a day, I need to write data in a new row in excel. After data is written, then I need to populate some columns using formulas.
When I run the script 1st time, it works fine. And you can see it in the picture.
When I run the script 2nd time, I am not seeing the expected result. The formula is not working right and I think my code has a bug and I need help here!

What I expect from 2nd run onwards is column E in cell E3 should populate with formula SUM(D3-D2)
column G in cell G3 should populate with formula SUM(F3-F2)
column H in cell should populate with formula SUM(G3+E3)

I have attached both pictures from 1st run and 2nd run. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code. Sheet is my worksheet name

```
import openpyxl
row = sheet.max_row + 1
sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=Date)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=Time)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value=PCTCLOSE)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=4, value=ValidResponse)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=6, value=CLOSE)
r = sheet.max_row
sheet.cell(row=r, column=5, value=f'=SUM(D{row + 1}-D{row})')
sheet.cell(row=r, column=7, value=f'=SUM(F{row + 1}-F{row})')
sheet.cell(row=r, column=8, value=f'=SUM(G{row + 1}+E{row + 1})')
sheet.cell(row=r, column=9, value=f'=SUM(G{row + 1}/H{row + 1})')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What formulas are being put in the cells after the later runs?

Comment: isn't `row + 1` the next empty row? don't you want the previous row instead?

Comment: Yes, row +1 is good for 1st run. From 2nd run, I need previous row.

Comment: `max_row` will change when you add cells. If you look at the cell formula you're actually creating you should be able to work out what you need to fix.